# ApacheDS fresh install fails after reboot

Tags: apache-ds

I've been wrestling with ApacheDS for the past 3 days and couldn't figure out what the problem is.

I've got a fresh install of ApacheDS 2.0.0-M9 on a fresh CenOS 6.3 with the latest JDK7 installed.

After first installing the downloaded ApacheDS RPM package, the service is automatically started and I can connect to ApacheDS from a remote DS Studio application and everything works fine.

The problem happens when I do a reboot. I have not touched ANY settings or played with any of the default values. I simply did a fresh install and then rebooted.

On examining the server, I can see the ApacheDS-default service is running. However, I can not connect to it from my DS Studio on a remote machine. I tried to shutdown the service, but I keep getting the following error:

```
/opt/apacheds-2.0.0_M9/bin/apacheds: line 418: kill: (3794) - No such process
Unable to stop ApacheDS - default
```

This is puzzling to me as I can clearly see the service is "running". The log files are not showing me any ERRORs, so I'm now completely at a loss.

Much appreciate any help or ideas.

Many thanks.

EDIT

I'm starting to suspect this is related to a potentially stale PID file. No matter how many times I reboot, it always tells me it's trying to kill process 3794 (it never changes).

I can't seem to find the PID location of ApacheDS. I've looked inside /var/run, but no mention of apacheds there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

you fix this issue by clearing the PID file, on debian the file is located under /var/lib/apacheds<version>/default/run/*.pid

remove any pid file located in that folder and you'll be good to go.

I was lead to the fix through this blog:

http://pugtex.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/taming-apache-directory-server-apacheds/

start ds by either /etc/init.d/apacheds start

or

/opt/apacheds<version>/bin/apacheds start default

Comment: Just a note for those who are using OS X.  This PID file is in /usr/local/apacheds-X/instances/default/run/  (where default is your instance name).

Comment: This also worked in Fedora 19

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because the user you have chosen during installation has limited access to /var/lock/subsys folder.

this folder is checked during machine shutdown to find out whether the apacheds process should be stopped(lock file with instance name should be there - in my case it is called "default").

in case it was not  closed properly during restart the lock file in /var/lib/apacheds/default/run/*.pid won't be removed and would prevent application from starting up.